# How to upgrade CDK bootstrapping?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have an environment which is already bootstrapped, and bootstrapping again (with CDK 1.106.1) doesn't seem to do anything:

```
$ cdk bootstrap aws://unknown-account/ap-southeast-2
'@aws-cdk/core:newStyleStackSynthesis' context set, using new-style bootstrapping
[…]
 ⏳  Bootstrapping environment aws://unknown-account/ap-southeast-2...
Trusted accounts:   (none)
Using default execution policy of 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'. Pass '--cloudformation-execution-policies' to customize.
```

However, the very next command warns about the bootstrap stack being too old:

```
$ cdk diff
[…]
Other Changes
[+] Unknown Rules: {"CheckBootstrapVersion":{"Assertions":[{"Assert":{"Fn::Not":[{"Fn::Contains":[["1","2","3"],{"Ref":"BootstrapVersion"}]}]},"AssertDescription":"CDK bootstrap stack version 4 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI."}]}}
```

What gives? I'm already running bootstrap with the latest CDK version. How do I upgrade the bootstrap version?

---

I've now deleted the "CDKToolkit" stack and re-bootstrapped successfully, but I'm *still* getting the same warning. What gives? I'm clearly running `cdk bootstrap` with a recent version of CDK.

I've now filed a [CDK issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14961) for this.

---

[Related project issue](https://github.com/linz/geostore/issues/761); [build](https://github.com/linz/geostore/runs/2732047231?check_suite_focus=true).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Answered by @rix0rrr](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14961#issuecomment-854459028):

> Nothing is actually wrong. The `cdk diff` is telling you about a `Rule` that got added to the template, but it doesn't actually know what the `Rule` means and so is printing it in a confusing way.
>
> The diff will disappear after your next deployment.

Answer (score 5):

I came to this page because I faced an issue related to bootstrap being considered old.

> "--cloudformation-execution-policies can only be passed for the modern
> bootstrap experience."

The below command from the article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cdk_pipeline.html was giving me an error. It turned out that export(linux/MacOS) and set(windows) were being mixed in my case.

```
export CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1
npx cdk bootstrap aws://315997497220/us-east-1 --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess aws://315997497220/us-east-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrapping using AWS profiles also works:

```
export CDK_NEW_BOOTSTRAP=1
cdk --profile=fortune-dev bootstrap
```

[image]